# Combine 2 tables in same datset into 1 table

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, xml-parsing

Ok, I have searched and searched debugged guessed and tried hundreds of different ways.

I have an xml Style webresponse read into a dataset and am trying to display 3 of the 10 created tables of the dataset in a datagridview.

How does this get done?

I can display any 1 of the tables but how can i display more then one without any keys? Just matching the rows of each table to each other in numerical order?

```
 StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
 string rspXml = reader.ReadToEnd();
 StringReader srxml = new StringReader(rspXml);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet("Shipment");
 ds.ReadXml(srxml);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
 dataGridView1.DataMember ="TotalCharges";
```

the three tables I need are "TotalCharges" "Shipment" and "Payments"

Comment: _matching the rows of each table to each other in numerical order_ Do you mean that you just want to display the data side-by-side (sort of) in one grid in the way the individual tables are ordered, or is there a common numeric field by which they can be joined?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [DataSet.Merge()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/803bh6bc.aspx) to create a new `DataSet` containing the data you want to display, then bind your `dataGridView1` to that.

Comment: How would i implement this to only merge the 3 tables needed?